# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at HTMLDivElement

Tags: javascript, html, carousel, slideshow

I am working on this code of an image Carousel and I am getting an error on the last function. what I want is to loop the image once it gets on the final image.

this is the error that I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at HTMLDivElement.slide.addEventListener (file:///C:/Users/uu/Desktop/New%20folder%20(3)/slider.js:27:25)

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>image slider project</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider.css">  
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
       <div class="slide">
            <img src="./bcg/img5.jpg" id="lastclone">
            <img src="./bcg/img1.jpeg">
            <img src="./bcg/img2.jpeg">
            <img src="./bcg/img3.jpeg">
            <img src="./bcg/img4.jpeg">
            <img src="./bcg/img5.jpg">
            <img src="./bcg/img1.jpeg" id="firstclone">
        </div>
       </div>

       <button class="pbtn">prevbtn</button>
       <button class="nbtn">nextbtn</button>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
var slide = document.querySelector(".slide");
var slideimg = document.querySelectorAll(".slide img");
var prevbtn = document.querySelector(".pbtn");
var nextbtn = document.querySelector(".nbtn");

var counter = 1;
var size = slideimg[0].clientWidth;

slide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter) + "px)";

nextbtn.addEventListener("click", next);
prevbtn.addEventListener("click", prev);

function next() {
  slide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
  counter++;
  slide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter) + "px)";
}

function prev() {
  slide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
  counter--;
  slide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter) + "px)";
}

slide.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
  if (slideimg[counter].id === "lastclone") {
    slide.style.transition = "none";
    counter = slideimg.lenght - 2;
    slide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter) + "px)";
  }
});
```

Comment: so `slideimg[counter]` is undefined.

Comment: console log `counter` in the event listener to see which element is it trying to access

Comment: Typo: you have `slideimg.lenght` instead of `slideimg.length`. Now **think a second about why this causes the error above** so that you can better understand and solve such problems yourself next time: The incorrect spelling means you are accessing a nonexistent property `lenght` on the object `slideimg`. Nonexistent properties always yield `undefined`. You then have essentially `undefined - 2` which is `NaN` ("not a number") because you cannot subtract a number from a non-number. Next time, you are therefore accessing `slideimg[NaN]` which is `undefined` too, so you then do `undefined.id`!

Comment: Thanks a lot, brother you just saved my life I was actually auditing each word but I think I just got overwhelmed so I couldn't focus on .length. anyways it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this kind of issue, try to think about the possible reasons of such a thing happening.

In this case, the error is pretty straighforward: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.slide.addEventListener (file:///C:/Users/uu/Desktop/New%20folder%20(3)/slider.js:27:25)*

Which means you have an error on line 27, column 25. It's trying to read the property 'id' (slideimg[counter]**.id**) of *undefined*. Meaning that slideimg[counter] returns undefined.

To go throught the process of debugging, you have 3 options:

1) you can spot the error just by looking at the code

2) add logs of the variables being is use at this particular place:

```
slide.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
  console.log( slideimg, counter );
  if (slideimg[counter].id === "lastclone") {
    slide.style.transition = "none";
    counter = slideimg.lenght - 2;
    slide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter) + "px)";
  }
});
```

3) use the debug feature of your browser to get an in-depth view of what is going under the hood:

```
slide.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
  // by adding this statement here, code execution will stop at runtime at this
  // particular place
  debugger;
  if (slideimg[counter].id === "lastclone") {
    slide.style.transition = "none";
    counter = slideimg.lenght - 2;
    slide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter) + "px)";
  }
});
```

More here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger